# "Extend" a HIVE query with another column: performance and best practices

Tags: hive, hiveql, window-functions

I have a `HIVE` query that computes some values using a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
  date,
  operating_system,
  action
FROM user_actions
GROUP BY date, operation_system, action;
```

This query correctly returns my first result, which is the number of unique users who took each action on each platform on each day.

Now, I also want to calculate the total number of unique users for each operating system on each day, and add that as a column. That way we can compare the number of users that did each action to the total number of users on that platform/day.

My attempt was the following:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
  date,
  operating_system,
  action,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY operation_system, date) AS TOTAL
FROM user_actions
GROUP BY date, operation_system, action;
```

I was wondering if there is a best practice between the two. The former doesn't even seem to work correctly? I think it is because the partition is being computed AFTER the `GROUP BY`, not at the same time.

If this is the case, then according to this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/tutorial-window.html, I may be able to move my function that computes total to a subquery, and then select from that, but this seems "hacky".

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

If you want to count number of unique user per os per day then you don't need `action` in your first query.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
  date,
  operating_system
FROM user_actions
GROUP BY date, operation_system;
```

When you use **window aggregate function** then you don't need `group by` clause at the end.

```
SELECT 
  date,
  operating_system,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY operation_system, date) AS TOTAL
FROM user_actions;
```

**Performance and Best Practices**

There is no universal answer here, performance of query depends on many things like indexes and joins. You need to decide based on your query requirements about the approach you want to pick.

**Window function** works over set of rows and perform calculation over them. When there is a large table then usually **sub query** is a bad idea over **window function** as **subquery** needs to hold all intermediate results.

In your case you are using **Window aggregate function count** which will not significantly better if you do this using `groupby`.